# Can one variable function as both dependent variable and moderating variable?

Tags: interaction, mediation

I wonder if one variable can function as both dependent and moderating variable

For example,

1. A affects B (A : IV / B : DV)
2. C is moderator between A and B
3. A also affects C (A : IV / C : DV)
4. D is moderator between A and C

[image]

Is this relationship possible? If it is possible, how can I test it statistically?